# How to select element using (this) inside IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap validation 
so this is my javascript

What I want to do is this

```
$("#create-form").submit(function(e) { 
    if ($("input").val() = "") {
        $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
    } 
}
```

By using (`this`) I will refer to `$("#create-form")` 
but want to refer to the Input by `$(this)`, is it possible somehow? 
I just don't want to repeat the if statement for each input

Comment: The value of 'this' is set depending on how it's called. So in this case 'this' will be the form itself.

Comment: can you post your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get a list of all input items in create-form

Then you can loop each input and check if the val is empty.

```
$("#create-form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $("#create-form :input").each(function(){
     var input = $(this); // This is the jquery object of the input, do what you want
     if(input.val() == ""){
         input.addClass("is-invalid");
     }

  });


});
```